# Pulseaudio – difference between digital / analog output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using a FiiO E10K external DAC for listening to music. When I open up pavucontrol and look at the configuration tab, I'm greeted with the following options to choose from:
[image: sound options]

Since the DAC is connected via USB, I would think that only the digital options should be shown, yet the analog options are present, and still work for sending audio. (Couldn't tell any difference in audio quality except for the digital options being quieter when at max volume) Why is it like this / which should I use then?

---

**Unrelated:** For people wondering what duplex means: Analog duplex means analog output + analog input, and digital duplex means digital output + digital input; notice that the longest options are one being analog, the other digital.